# How do I code PHP Worker Processes?

Tags: php, performance, imagemagick

I have a PHP script that needs to run some pretty hefty imagemagick commands.

These commands may be run at the same time by multiple users, so user a, b, c, and d would all be running the same task. I want to make it into a background process, so I can use jQuery, for example, to show a loading bar during processing.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Or, is there another method that may be easier?

Comment: Have you considered using AJAX? I mean, just calling a request and starting up the server-side things with it and showing a loading bar while no response has been received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite some guides how to create Deamons with PHP:
http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/

Or how to background a process:
http://waynepan.com/2007/10/11/how-to-use-ignore_user_abort-to-do-process-out-of-band/

You could create a deamon running in the background, reading from a database table that contains all jobs that need to be worked on and then you can check with your frontend process for that table every once in a while until all jobs have cleared for that specific process.

You can also use a message queue for that, so you can use multiple deamons in parallel (for example on multicore systems) without conflicting.

Comment: By the way... be careful some shared web hosters aren't fans of multiple long running php processes ;)

Answer (score -2):

I seek for hours, at least, the solution was very easy for me using **Cron Jobs**. In **cPanel** you can go to Advanced -> Cron Jobs, and there schedule a task using a PHP script in Command line.

A Command example that execute a script php:

```
/usr/bin/wget http://www.example.com/miscript.php
```

or better:

```
php /home/USER/public_html/miscript.php
```